# dismissview controller is not working inside splitView or tabBar controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

**Description:** I have a Spilt view controller which has the `masterController` to display all the menu items and the secondary controller(`DetailViewController1`) is to display few details. Now I have `DetailViewController2` which displays some other information.

**Flow:** SplitViewController which has the `MasterViewController`(table view for menu) -> `DetailViewController1` -> `DetailViewController2`

**Problem:** If I present the `DetailViewController2` using `show` segue then it is fine. If I use `show detail` segue then the navigation bar back button in the `DetailViewController2` is **not dismissing my `DetailViewController2` to go back to the `DetailViewController1`**.

Even if I use `show` segue it fails to dismiss. What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You should use show only, Because Show detail segue replace the controller not push it

From Apple

**Show Detail:**

> Present the content in the detail area. If the app is displaying a
>   master and detail view, the new content replaces the current detail.
>   If the app is only displaying the master or the detail, the content
>   replaces the top of the current view controller stack.

You can find more about it here

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/Chapters/StoryboardSegue.html

Comment: Even if I change to **show** segue the back button is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use two navigation controllers as the MasterViewController and DetailViewController of the `UISplitViewController.`

Embed your `MasterViewController` and `DetailViewController1` in the nav controllers.

In `DetailViewController1,` when 'More Detail' button is clicked (or whatever triggers navigation to `DetailViewController2`):

```
{
    let secondVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailViewController2") as! DetailViewController2
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(DetailViewController2, animated: true)
}
```

This will present `DetailViewController2` and the nav controller will handle navigating back to `DetailViewController1` for free.

More info, including other benefits of using dual nav controller approach, here: http://nshipster.com/uisplitviewcontroller/